# Keep up to two of each text string type for a give name

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, text

**Background**

I have the following `df`, which is a modification of question: *[keep rows that start with certain text strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498726/keep-rows-that-start-with-certain-text-strings)*.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['\n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere', 
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere is', 
                             '\n[BASEBALL]\nTHIS SOUNDS right',
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nLikes sports', 
                             '\n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fanatic',
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nReal fan', 
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nTHIS SOUNDS good',
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan',
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nRARELY IS a fan',
                             '\n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan',
                             '\n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fan'
                            ], 

                          'P_ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 
                          'P_Name' : ['J J SMITH', 
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'J J SMITH',
                                      'MARY HYDER', 
                                      'MARY HYDER', 
                                      'MARY HYDER', 
                                      'MARY HYDER']
                         })
```

**Output**

```
    P_ID    P_Name  Text
0   1   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere
1   2   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere is
2   3   J J SMITH   \n[BASEBALL]\nTHIS SOUNDS right
3   4   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nLikes sports
4   5   J J SMITH   \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fanatic
5   6   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nReal fan
6   7   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nTHIS SOUNDS good
7   8   MARY HYDER  \n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan
8   9   MARY HYDER  \n[SPORTS FAN]\nRARELY IS a fan
9   10  MARY HYDER  \n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan
10  11  MARY HYDER  \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fan
```

**Goal**

For every name in `P_Name` (e.g. `J J SMITH`) keep *up to* two examples of each "text type" e.g.`\n[SPORTS FAN]\n`  from the `Text` column.

**Desired Output**

```
    P_ID    P_Name  Text
0   1   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere
1   2   J J SMITH   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere is
2   3   J J SMITH   \n[BASEBALL]\nTHIS SOUNDS right
3   5   J J SMITH   \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fanatic
4   8   MARY HYDER  \n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan
5   9   MARY HYDER  \n[SPORTS FAN]\nRARELY IS a fan
6   11  MARY HYDER  \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fan
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `groupby` + `head`

```
df.groupby(['P_Name', df.Text.str.split('\n').str.get(1)]).head(2)
```

---

```
                         Text  P_ID      P_Name
0                 \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere     1   J J SMITH
1              \n[SPORTS FAN]\nHere is     2   J J SMITH
2      \n[BASEBALL]\nTHIS SOUNDS right     3   J J SMITH
4    \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fanatic     5   J J SMITH
7   \n[SPORTS FAN]\nReally Big big fan     8  MARY HYDER
8      \n[SPORTS FAN]\nRARELY IS a fan     9  MARY HYDER
10       \n[BASEBALL]\nRARELY IS a fan    11  MARY HYDER
```